# Automatically refreshing a Python script after a certain time

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, refresh

I have a script that takes a trains departure time from a Website and saves the difference between that time and datetime.now in a variable called resp.
Resp contains the time until the next train departs.

Then it creates a new window using Tkinter:

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text=resp)
        label.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).grid(sticky="nsew")
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.geometry('1920x1080')

    root.mainloop()
```

and displays resp in that window.

My problem is that the departure time (resp) should always be up to date, which means it would have to refresh resp(which means it would have to run the code that is not included in this question) every second.

Including the whole script in a while True: doesn't work and would probably not be an efficient way of doing it.

Is there a way of doing this?

My Code:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1romGOeUqKa2B-fKQyily6DXDqZTY9xMf

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multithreading. A separate thread can refresh `resp` every second, while your main thread handles displaying `resp`.

Comment: multithreading is only one of at least three ways to solve this. I think "You _need_ to use multithreading" is a bit too strong of a phrase.

Comment: What is the third way apart from multithreading and 'Tkinter.after' as you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: You could use a form of multiprocessing.

Comment: I've now looked into multithreading and tried to implement it into my code. I created a thread that got the times from the website and then calculated the time until the next train departs (resp). I created another thread that runs the Tkinter code included in my question. I then started both threads with t.start and t2.start. it threw out some errors, one is name 'resp' not defined. Do you have any idea why this happened and could you maybe include a little sample code in your Answer about how you'd use multithreading in my example?

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter provides a method named `after` that lets you schedule work to be run in the future. If the work to be performed can execute in under a few hundred milliseconds, you can use this instead of something more complex like multithreading or multiprocessing.

Widgets have a method named `configure`, which allows you to change attributes of the widget after it has been created. You can use this method to change the data displayed in the widget.

For example, let's assume you have a function called `get_resp`. Maybe it calls a rest service, maybe it reads a file, it doesn't really matter. If you want to call this function and update the display every 10 seconds, for example, you might do it like this:

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=resp)
        ...
    def refresh_display(self):
        # get the new value
        resp = self.get_resp()

        # update the display with the new value
        self.label.configure(text=resp)

        # have this function be called again in 10 seconds
        self.after(10000, self.refresh_display)
```

If `self.get_resp()` takes too long, another option would be to create a thread that calls `self.get_resp()` and then sets a variable with the new value (or pushes it on a thread-safe queue). You could then modify `refresh_display` to update the variable with whatever is stored in the variable or whatever is in the queue.

Comment: I tried to implement this into my code, but it didn't work. First, I just copy-pasted your code into mine and after running it, it created a window as always, but it didn't update. Then I wrapped all my Code except the tkinter part in a def called get_resp, which didn't work too. If you need to see the code, I included a link in my Answer

Comment: I've now managed to get it to display my resp in a new window with the code in your answer, but it still doesn't refresh automatically.